# Upgrade existing Ghost installation on Openshift

Tags: openshift, ghost-blog

I'm running my personal blog on Openshift cloud (from Redhat) which is running through Ghost 0.4.2. I've used this quickstart for deployment of Ghost: https://www.openshift.com/quickstarts/ghost

Now the quickstart upgraded to Ghost 0.5 (latest release of Ghost). is there any way I can upgrade my current Ghost installation to 0.5 from 0.4.2 without creating new app using the upgraded quickstart?
I mean, I don't want to create new app using the upgraded quickstart. I just want to upgrade my existing Ghost installation, so my site's content, custom theme etc. will be intact. Just Ghost version will be upgraded to 0.5. As Openshift forum retires, they asked to get support from here. So I'm asking the question here. any help?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to upgrade would be to git clone your application to your local computer, add the new updated repository from here (https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-ghost-quickstart) or this one if you are using the mysql version (https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-ghost-mysql-quickstart) as another 'remote' and then merge that code into your existing code, and git add, git commit, and git push to get that code up to your OpenShift gear.

Comment: This repository contains old Ghost version and can't be used for update to latest until OpenShift updates them.